# Python - assign value and check condition in IF statment

Tags: python

I have this code:

```
str = func(parameter)
if not str:
   do something.
```

the function `func()` return a `string` on success and `''` on failure.
The `do something` should happen only if `str` actualy contain a string.

Is it possible to do the assigmnt to str on the `IF` statment itself?

Comment: you should define that inside the function `func`.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of "[https://stackoverflow.com/q/8826521/90527](Python: avoiding if condition for this code?)" (though this question is more focused on the general problem, rather than on specific code, and is thus a better expression of the issue).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In one word: no. In Python assignment is a statement, not an expression.

Answer (score 1):

Why not try it yourself,

```
if not (a = some_func()):
  do something
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

**So, no.**

Answer (score 1):

[PEP 572](https://peps.python.org/pep-0572/) added syntax for [assignment expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#assignment-expressions). Specifically, using `:=` (called the "walrus operator") for assignment is an expression, and thus can be used in `if` conditions.

```
if not (thing := findThing(name)):
    thing = createThing(name, *otherArgs)
```

Note that `:=` is easy to abuse. If the condition is anything more complex than a direct test (i.e. `if value := expresion:`) or a `not` applied to the assignment result (such as in the 1st sample above), it's likely more readable to write the assignment on a separate line.

Answer (score 0):

With the below code snippet, if the func returns a string of length > 0 only then the do something part will happen

```
str = func(parameter)
if str:
   do something
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, it's the shortest version I could come up with:

```
if func(parameter):
   do something.
```