# Check and assign return value of function in one line

Tags: python

I'm assigning many properties to a dictionary, like this:

```
dict = {
    "prop1": round(myfunc1(), 2),
    "prop2": round(myfunc2(), 2),
}
```

`myfunc()` returns either `None` or a `float` number.

I need to do this:

```
result = myfunc()
if result is not None:
    result = round(result, 2)
```

But in one line.

The reason a normal Python one liner would not be ok is that `myfunc()` is a long and resource intensive function, and I definitely don't want to call it twice or implement any lazy loading inside it. This would not be ok:

```
result = round(myfunc(), 2) if myfunc() is not None else None
```

Is this doable?

Comment: This is exactly why the walrus operator (`:=`) was introduced in 3.8. Not available in previous versions though.

Comment: Aw, damn... I'm running 3.7

Comment: @d_kennetz `TypeError: type NoneType doesn't define __round__ method`

Comment: I see, good point

Comment: Why does it have to be on one line? Why do you care?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, see updated question

Comment: You could make a helper function or lambda: `round2 = lambda x: x if x is None else round(x, 2)`. Then create the dict with `"prop1": round2(myfunc1()),....`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python - assign value and check condition in IF statment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39739510/90527)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok... this is pretty horrible, and I'm not proud, but if it's gotta be one line:

```py
result = next(None if v is None else round(v, 2) for v in (my_func(),))
```

Is it worth avoiding two lines over? Only you can know.

Answer (score 3):

Python 3.8 (applying Walrus Operator)

```
result = round(f, 2) if f := myfunc() is not None else None
```